# Search Multiple Fields from a single form in php

Tags: php

I have the following records

```
first name    last name   id
----------    ---------   ---
John           Doe        68
Jane           Doe        69
```

and I have single search box. What I'm trying to do is a search from a single form box.

For example, the user will type in the last name `Doe` and all instances of `Doe` will show up.

How would I go about creating a search function that will split the data and search the correct field based on the data that is based on the input.

Thank you

Comment: What if someone's first name is Doe?  Should that be included when someone searches 'Doe'?  Do you only want exact matches  or should partial matches be included?  What about searching by `id`?  Right now, this question is _too broad_. Also, "I have the following records".  Where? In a text file? In a database?  If a database, what kind?  Do you have _any_ code yet?

Comment: I should have explained in more detail.. This is a database search and partial matches should be included.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution myself and here is what I did.

1. I put the search item as an array.
2. I put the values of the parameters in a for loop in the query